# How to run source command using ActiveRecord::Base in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to execute sql file using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("source file_path.sql")
```

I am using Rails 2.3.2 and getting error that incorrect mysql syntax but when running same command in mysql console it is working fine.

Please comment if you know something around this???

Thanks

Comment: Post the full stacktrace. Does the error originate in rails or mysql?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(File.read("source file_path.sql"))` ?

Comment: Hey @swapnil patil:  thanks for help but I am using Rails 2.3.2
it is throwing error..

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
query = <<-SQL
  Your working sql query from sql console
SQL

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
return result
```

Comment: That's what he has.

Comment: Thanks Swapnil Patil, but I am using Rails 2.3.2
and it is throwing error 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source filepath.sql'

Comment: Can you post your sql query here? @jaswinderahuja

Comment: sure @SwapnilPatil,

I am creating trigger in sql file and trying to execute sql file using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("source filename.sql")

here it doen't matter as long as query syntax in sql file is correct but the point it how to execute sql file using ActiveRecord.
Thanks..